# Firebase - limit write to authorized user

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am writing an app where I have users, and each user has trips.
I have managed to authenticate and insert user's data. Now I want to define rules for the trips list.
Currently I can't get the simulator to work even with the same definitions (getting write/read permissions to users, but failing for trips, see pics):
[image: Failing for 'trips']
[image: passing for 'users']
This is what I have that is failing:

```
{
  "rules": {    
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid"
      },
      "trips" : {
        "$uid" : {
            ".write": "$uid === auth.uid",
            ".read": "$uid === auth.uid"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What I actually want eventually is:

```
{
  "rules": {    
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid"
      },
      "trips" : {
        "$tid" : {
            ".indexOn": ["uid"],
            ".write": "<only if child field 'uid' is same as auth.uid>",
            ".read": "auth != null"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you've nested your "trips" rules under the "users" rules. They should both be under the "rules" node. Like this:

```
{
  "rules": {    
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    },
    "trips" : {
      "$tid" : {
          ".write": "$tid === auth.uid",
          ".read": "auth!=null",
          ".indexOn":"uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Silly me :(  Thanks!